# Is it good to use two tables separately, or one table with both data within?

Tags: mysql, sql

Which approach is good for creating two tables in a database?

### Approach 1

#### Phone Table:

```
id  name  
1   blabla  
2   blabla  
3   blabla  
.  
..
```

#### Laptop Table:

```
id   name  
1    blabla  
2    blabla  
3    blabla  
.  
..
```

### Approach 2

#### Products Table:

```
id  name     type  
1   blabla   laptop  
2   blabla   phone  
3   blabla   laptop  
.  
..
```

Comment: As the real contents of `blabla` would effect the correctness of an answer, can you give a little more detail

Comment: because they are really blabla, and are not important, I want to know, to have separate tables or one table with both values?  for example: if I want to fetch data I can say:  SELECT * FROM Phone  and  SELECT * FROM Laptop  but I can also put them together and say:  SELECT * FROM Products Where type=phone  and  SELECT * FROM products Where type=laptop    I want to know which is better THANKS

Comment: What you are actually storing is important. If you want a good answer, you have to put the effort into asking a good question!

Comment: I'd probably have a products table. What will be the difference between a phone and a laptop in 5 years?

Comment: @jarlh Agreed. at the rate they are going, a phone will be the size of a laptop too...

Comment: @jarlh Assuming nothing: no adding no editing the tables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches have their uses. You need to ask yourself what kind of data you need for the different types of products, and how are you going to use the data. If you are planning on making a store, all of your products need something in the line of:

- Name
- Category
- Subcategory (optional)
- Price
- Description

This would be a good time to have laptops and phones in the same table.

However, if you are making a website where you distinctively categorize laptops and phones seperately,and for example have a template to display each type, you might want different data for the different products. Laptops and phones are so similar, that I can't think of any specifics right now. However, my first example could include something as different as apples, or a spatula for that matter. You can see how screen size, battery time and resolution would be completely irrelevant for the latter, while the five bullet points listed would make sense on all sellable products.

What you need to consider in your case is what are you going to use the data for? What kind of extensions in data might you need in the future?

This will hopefully give you a good idea if you should use one or two tables for the similar items.